# How to hide my Java / Swing program in ALT + TAB menu?

Tags: java, swing, hide, jdialog

Currently I am trying to create a small Overlay that should not show in the alt+tab menu.  I am using a `JDialog` in JRE 1.8.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: *"Is there any way to achieve this?"*  'Native code' (read that as 'not Java code').

Comment: Side note: which OS are you using (OK,most likely Windows; but you see, there are other OSes that also use alt-tab for that ;-) ... besides - did you do any prior investigation? It is expected that people **try** to figure answers themselves before coming here ...

Comment: Currenty I am using Windows 8.1, but it should work in future Windows versions, too. ( Windows 10 ..) 
I don't really care about other OSes at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `JDialog.setType( Window.Type.UTILITY );`